# Reading csv directly from another program

Tags: r

How can I tell `R` to import the csv-data in the `read.table` command from the stdout of another program instead of from a file? I want `R` to launch my csv-export-utility on its own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the help page from `help(connections)` and the documentation of the `pipe()` function.

Here is a complete (but nonsensical) example where we write a csv file

```
R> write.csv(iris, file="/tmp/iris.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

and then just use `cat` to show its content on stdin and read that via `read.csv()` from the `pipe()`:

```
R> newiris <- read.csv(pipe("cat /tmp/iris.csv"))
```

What we get is what we had, expected:

```
R> head(newiris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
R> all.equal(iris, newiris)
[1] TRUE
R>
```

Comment: Gosh, that just gave me the idea of `pipe("cat < /dev/stdin")`. I feel dirty now, but it does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [named pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe), but this question should be on stack overflow.